# Linq Exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

When I run this LINQ query:

```vb
Dim CurrQ = From c In db.CurrentMonthTables Where c.MonthNumber = Val(CmbMonthNumber.Text) And c.Year = Val(CmbYear.Text) And c.Exist = True
```

I get:

> ...object reference not set to an instance of an object...

Comment: Make sure that this `db.CurrentMonthTables` is an instance not a type and try: `Dim CurrQ = From c In db.CurrentMonthTables Where c.MonthNumber = CInt(CmbMonthNumber.Text) AndAlso c.Year = CInt(CmbYear.Text) AndAlso c.Exist`

Comment: Note that @JQSOFT used `CInt` instead of the old VB6 `Val`. Val can produce unexpected results.